# How to calculate wet bulb globe temperature (WBGT) using only temperature and humidity?

Tags: temperature, measurements, humidity, data-analysis

Greetings fellow scholars,

I'm trying to answer the question above because I've come across WBGT calculators like this one (https://www.climatechip.org/heat-stress-index-calculation) and I don't understand how the answers are derived using the Liljegren method without more variables (other than temperature, humidity and assumptions on direct sunlight and wind speed).

The paper, [Liljegren et al. (2008)](https://doi.org/10.1080/15459620802310770), method is pay walled. I've tried digging into the code of projects like [this one](https://rdrr.io/github/anacv/HeatStress/src/R/wbgt.Liljegren.R) but they're using more variables.

If anyone can give an explanation of what's going on with these calculators or point me to a code repo/paper where I can try learn more, please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Explicit Calculations of Wet-Bulb Globe Temperature Compared With Approximations and Why It Matters for Labor Productivity*](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2021EF002334) might help explain what's going on.

Liljegren's method appears to be calculation intense. It involves three equations, the two main ones are for T<sub>w</sub> & T<sub>g</sub>, equations 3 & 5. The equations needs to be solved by iteration.

[image]  $..............(3)$

[image]  $..............(4)$

[image]  $..............(5)$

By ignoring direct sunlight & wind speed, the web page you link to is simplifying things & producing an approximation; something similar to calculating sW BGT, equation 1.

[image]    $.............(1)$